# My Hyundai won’t start but have power

Tags: hyundai, no-crank-no-start

I was driving on the highway and suddenly it just died out of nowhere, so I put it neutral till I could stop on the side of the freeway. And I tried and tried to start it but nothing. I still have all power to the vehicle but it won’t turn over or anything of the sort. I had power to the vehicle even when it just suddenly died. I got the car towed home and put some jumper cables on it just in case it had low voltage and still nothing it won’t even turn over but again still have power to it. Help please

Comment: Do all the dashboard warning lights light up as normal when the ignition is turned on?  Do all the electrical items still work? e.g. wipers, lights, horn....   Does the car have a impact detecting sensor that disables the engine following an impact?  Check the owners manual.

Comment: Have you tried using a different set of keys?

Comment: Yes all lights come on all good. When i pulled over to the side of the highway it had a little bit of smoke come from it and I looked and couldn’t find anything then I tried to start it again and then a little bit more smoke came from it and every time after that no smoke but still all my lights came on.